# Por que minha função só retorna "par"?

Tags: javascript, funções, if, for, return

```
 function parimp(n){
         for(var i = 0; i <= n; i++){
             if(i % 2 == 0){
                 return "par";
             }else{
                 return "impar";
             }
         }
     }
     
      var s = parimp(25);
      console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por que é o que mandou fazer. Um `return` serve para encerrar a função, se não queria que ela fosse encerrada não coloque um `return`.

Talvez quisesse fazer isto:

```js
function parimp(n) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) console.log(i % 2 == 0 ? "par" : "impar");
}
parimp(25);
```

Ou melhor ainda:

```js
function parimp(n) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= n; i += 2) console.log("par\nimpar");
}
parimp(25);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/OddEven.js).

Se o número for fixo em 25 dá pra simplificar mais ainda.

Comment: Entendi. return encerra a função. Valeu :)